# Race condition in ProducerConsumerQueue from Threading in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I think there is a race condition in `ProducerConsumerQueue` from
http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx#_Signaling_with_Event_Wait_Handles. Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class ProducerConsumerQueue : IDisposable
{
  EventWaitHandle _wh = new AutoResetEvent (false);
  Thread _worker;
  readonly object _locker = new object();
  Queue<string> _tasks = new Queue<string>();

  public ProducerConsumerQueue()
  {
    _worker = new Thread (Work);
    _worker.Start();
  }

  public void EnqueueTask (string task)
  {
    lock (_locker) _tasks.Enqueue (task);
    _wh.Set();
  }

  public void Dispose()
  {
    EnqueueTask (null);     // Signal the consumer to exit.
    _worker.Join();         // Wait for the consumer's thread to finish.
    _wh.Close();            // Release any OS resources.
  }

  void Work()
  {
    while (true)
    {
      string task = null;
      lock (_locker)
        if (_tasks.Count > 0)
        {
          task = _tasks.Dequeue();
          if (task == null) return;
        }
      if (task != null)
      {
        Console.WriteLine ("Performing task: " + task);
        Thread.Sleep (1000);  // simulate work...
      }
      else
        _wh.WaitOne();         // No more tasks - wait for a signal
    }
  }
}
```

Consider following execution where C is consumer thread and P is producer thread and t1, t2, t3 are for the time of execution:

**t1:** C does not enter task execution because the queue is empty

```
lock (_locker)
        if (_tasks.Count > 0)
```

**t2:** P invokes `EnqueueItem(action)`

**t3:** C reaches `_wh.WaitOne();` and waits forever (supposing that the producer stopped adding new values)

Comment: Mistake in the book? Nonsense! On a serious side, producer is *your* call of `EnqueueTask`. I don't understand your comment `t1`, you reference peace of code of consumer and say producer.

Comment: `Work` consumes the queue, and whomever invokes `EnqueueTask` will produce items. The worker loop only exits if a null task is enqueued, and should generally sit on the last line waiting for the Set event.  But agree that the number of branches and reasoning over null looks quite ropey in the consumer loop. Of course, in production code we would use a more trusted mechanism like `ConcurrentQueue`.

Comment: Why will the code "wait forever" at `_wh.WaitOne()`? The code that calls `EnqueueItem(action)` is going to call `_wh.Set()` at some point.

Comment: Also, as other comments may be alluding to, your terminology seems to be backwards. The producer is the code that generates ("produces") tasks and adds them to the queue - the code that calls `EnqueueTask`. The consumer is the code that pulls tasks *from* the queue and "consumes" them. This reversal is especially obvious where in your parenthetical at the end of the question, you state "the consumer stopped producing" which should have been a warning that the terms you're using aren't the correct way around.

Comment: @Sinatr Thanks, C and P fixed

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Because the `EnqueueItem(action)` may never be called in future. Starvation... Thanks for pointing the consumer/producer mistake - it was a nonsense :)

Comment: If `EnqueueAction` has *finished* running before we reach `t3` then the event is already `Set` and `WaitOne` won't wait.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Just checked it in unit/integration tests. You are right! Thanks for helping. Post as answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every call to `EnqueueItem` does two things - it first ensures that there is at least one item in the queue (P1), and *then* it calls `Set` on the `AutoResetEvent` (P2).

The consumer performs three activities in a loop - it tries to dequeue an item (C1), it then either processes the item (C2a) or it waits for the `AutoResetEvent` to become set (C2b).

P1 and C1 are the items protected by the lock and therefore we know that one of these will occur before the other, and they will not be interleaved.

For C1 to conclude that no items are in the list, P1 must occur after it. But, since we know that P2 follows, we know that the `AutoResetEvent` will definitely become set by P2 at *some* future point in time, and so the C2b wait will always be satisfied.